# Unknown tokens not possible to sell and buy

Tags: tokens, wallets, scam

guys!

I habe 4 unknown tokens hidden in my wallet! I can not buy and sell them but there are two sites like „OP Etherscan“ and „contract“ where I can click on it.

Of course I did not click on it. I tried to sell it but it is not working of course. Am I hacked now and what should I do?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Anyone can send you tokens. You can't stop it.

Malicious actors sometimes create malicious tokens and send them to random users. I don't really know all of the ways they try to trick you, but it's safe to just ignore those.

So whenever you see weird tokens in your wallet you can just ignore them. It doesn't mean that you would be hacked.

Comment: I tried to sell it but it‘s not working of course because I didn‘t know it and I do not want to have them. 

But I did not click on any link… I hope my wallet is not hacked because I tried to sell it :(

Comment: Just ignore it. Most likely you're ok, but it's much safer to not try to interact with it at all.

Comment: Yes! I just klicked once and checked something is wrong… after some hours I got the same one again and two other tokens… AAVE.asia, BLAST and BRC-20.ws… I didn‘t klicked on sell anymore and of course not on the links… sorry for asking so much I‘m jusg afraid… You think that I‘m safe?

Comment: Impossible to say. If you're in doubt, it's probably best to move your assets to a fresh wallet, to give you a peace of mind. But most likely you are safe already.

Comment: So when I claim my tokens I should just move them to an other wallet I have and I‘m safe? :)